# Display the length of a string on the page

Tags: javascript, string, innerhtml

I have a simple program that stores male, female and unisex names, you click a button and one is chosen at random and displayed on the page.

I am constantly adding new names into the database, so I want a simple javascript that records how many names are stored in each separate database (male, female and unisex) and displays in in a text that reads "There are currently ### males name, ### female names, and ### unisex names."

The site is live at: http://surrealmayhem.com/stuff/name_generator.html

The only things I can find online is a console.log using

```
    var = randomOtherNames.length;
```

but I need it to display in the html via a span or bold tag and an ID name. I know it would be something along the lines of

```
    document.getElementById("male_num");
```

but passed that, Im not sure how to put it all together and make it display on the page. Im still very new to javascript, and I dont entirely understand how the text that does display when you click the buttons even works. I feel like I might be able to reuse the script I already have, but I could use some help.

```
<button Onclick="click" id="other_button" style="font-size: 25px;"> Click Me </button>
<br /><br />
<b id="other_name" style="font-size: 25px;"></b>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                            var other_string = randomOtherNames.length;
              var randomOtherNames = [
"Jamie",
"Shannon",
"Kelly",
"Aeron",
"Shain",
"Kasey",
"Jordan",
"Jesse / Jessie",
"Sage",
"Evan",
"Alex",
"Stephen",
"Renee",
"Tracy",
"Avery",
"Dallas",
"Denver",
"Taylor",
"Elliot",
"Terry",
"Jeri",
"Percy",
"Raven",
"Jean",
"Jan",
"Christian",
"Adrian",
"Jude",
"Quinn",
"Piper",
"Harper",
"Payton",
"Walker",
"Cameron",
"Terran",
"Riley",
"River",
"Andren",
"Camden",
"Jiles",
"Pax",
"Rayne",
"Skylar",
"Kalin",
"Justice",
"July",
"Kensington",
"Kendall",
"Grey",
"Genesis",
"Hollis",
"Keagan",
"Kai",
"Bristol",
"Angel",
"Azure",
"Bailey",
"Carmen",
"Echo",
"Embry",
"Ember",
"Gale",
"Freedom",
"Haven",
"Kyler",
"Kylan",
"Miracle",
"Myka",
"Peace",
"Zene",
"Winter",
"Xannon",
"Valor",
"Urban",
"Valentine",
"Storm",
"Tai",
"Shae",
"Sailor",
"Red",
"Reign",
"Ramsey",
"Reed",
"Reggie",
"Ocean",
"Nalo",
"Neo",
"London",
"Ash",
"Brook",
"Crane",
"Crimson",
"Corin",
"Cresant",
"Indigo",
"Jazz",
"Cassidy",
"Kin",
"Monroe",
"Moral",
"Poet",
"Ryder",
"Saxton",
"Sidney",
"Tanner",
"Torrance",
"Torrin",
"Lex / Lexi",
"Zane",
"Zanas",
"Ari",
"Brynn",
"Greer",
"Kennedy",
"Lyle",
"Lonnie",
"Rune",
"Rylan",
"Sparrow",
"Sunny",
"Emerald",
"Cloud",
"Star",
"Kensey",



              ];



              var other_div = document.getElementById("other_name");

              document.getElementById("other_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
                    randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random()*randomOtherNames.length-1));
                    newText = randomOtherNames[randomIndex];
                    other_div.innerHTML = newText;
              });
          </script>
```

Comment: Can you display your attempts of doing this and when you say "put it together" do you mean you want the name to show in a div/span like "jamie Shannon Kelly.." ?

Comment: Yea. Im trying to work it out and I found an example using document.write, but its not displaying. I think my biggest problem may be simple syntax.

Comment: var = howmany_other = getElementById("unisex_num");
document.write(randomOtherNames.length);

Comment: Loops and innerHTML are the parts Im fuzzy on. I dont quite yet understand how they work.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve ? can you show sample output ?

Comment: I want the number of how many names are stored to display on the page inside a sentence, via a tag like "There are <b id="male_num"> </b> male names" and it'll show up on the page as "There are 250 male names"

Comment: Then use `document.getElementById("male_num").innerHTML=randomOtherNames.length;` I'm sure you know how to add text into this?

Comment: I'm confused to what is it you want. Are you wanting to display the amount of names in your array or display a name at random because one minute you ask to display at random and now you're talking about getting the amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top, add an element that you will use to display the count. Then in your script, set the innerHTML for the new element:

```js
var randomOtherNames = ["Jamie", "Shannon", "Kelly", "Aeron", "Shain", "Kasey", "Jordan", "Jesse / Jessie", "Sage", "Evan", "Alex", "Stephen", "Renee", "Tracy", "Avery", "Dallas", "Denver", "Taylor", "Elliot", "Terry", "Jeri", "Percy", "Raven", "Jean", "Jan", "Christian", "Adrian", "Jude", "Quinn", "Piper", "Harper", "Payton", "Walker", "Cameron", "Terran", "Riley", "River", "Andren", "Camden", "Jiles", "Pax", "Rayne", "Skylar", "Kalin", "Justice", "July", "Kensington", "Kendall", "Grey", "Genesis", "Hollis", "Keagan", "Kai", "Bristol", "Angel", "Azure", "Bailey", "Carmen", "Echo", "Embry", "Ember", "Gale", "Freedom", "Haven", "Kyler", "Kylan", "Miracle", "Myka", "Peace", "Zene", "Winter", "Xannon", "Valor", "Urban", "Valentine", "Storm", "Tai", "Shae", "Sailor", "Red", "Reign", "Ramsey", "Reed", "Reggie", "Ocean", "Nalo", "Neo", "London", "Ash", "Brook", "Crane", "Crimson", "Corin", "Cresant", "Indigo", "Jazz", "Cassidy", "Kin", "Monroe", "Moral", "Poet", "Ryder", "Saxton", "Sidney", "Tanner", "Torrance", "Torrin", "Lex / Lexi", "Zane", "Zanas", "Ari", "Brynn", "Greer", "Kennedy", "Lyle", "Lonnie", "Rune", "Rylan", "Sparrow", "Sunny", "Emerald", "Cloud", "Star", "Kensey"];


var other_string = randomOtherNames.length;
var other_div = document.getElementById("other_name");
var other_count_div = document.getElementById("other_name_count");

//populate the innerHTML of "other_count_div" on page load:
other_name_count.innerHTML = randomOtherNames.length;

var findName = function() {
        randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random() * randomOtherNames.length - 1));
        newText = randomOtherNames[randomIndex];
        other_div.innerHTML = newText;
        other_name_count.innerHTML = randomOtherNames.length;
    };
document.getElementById("other_button").addEventListener("click", findName);
```

```html
<button Onclick="click" id="other_button" style="font-size: 25px;"> Click Me </button>
<br /><br />
<b id="other_name" style="font-size: 25px;"></b>
<span id="other_name_count"></span>
```

Comment: Thats 99% of what I needed, thanks! Is there a way to make the number display without needing to click the button?

Comment: Sure. I will edit the answer to show you how that can be done.

Comment: Its working, but, not where I need it to work. I have my span tag set in another div, and it wont display there. It'll display inside the div with the rest of the code, not but outside of it. Is there anything that can be done about that?

Comment: Looks like you have two spans with id="other_name_count" on the page. If you remove the one inside the div, then the one outside the div will get populated correctly.

Comment: Yea.. when I do that the whole Unisex name section stops working

Comment: Now Im totally stumped. It will work when I put the span tag in a few oddball places, but not where I want it to be. I noticed the tag was working in between two divs, which I thought meant it would work if I just put it outside of a div, but, I reworked my code, eliminated the last div and made it all html, but, the span tag still wont work in the spot I want it to. I am so confused.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much! I am going to scour this thing and learn where I messed up. Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh yay I found what you changed immediately. This will help me learn a lot. =)